# ¿Dónde puedo guardar la llave del cifrado AES?

Tags: seguridad, encriptación, lenguaje-agnóstico, ingenieria-del-software

Estoy trabajando en una base de datos MySQL y una aplicación en C#, utilizo el cifrado **AES** para los datos importantes de los usuarios en la base de datos usando las funciones `AES_ENCRYPT()` y `AES_DECRYPT()`.

El problema está en que no sé dónde debo almacenar la llave para encriptar y desencriptar. ¿Dentro de la base de datos? ¿Dentro de la aplicación?

**¿Dónde se guardaría la llave del cifrado AES de forma segura?**

Comment: Pues si nunca lo vas a cambiar (que no creo) lo puedes dejar en una variable `static` asi `private static string key = "key";` ya que al desensamblar ese código los valores estáticos no se ven (ildasm desensamblador).

Comment: Hola Alejandro, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Answer (score 2):

En el código **NO** porqué:

1. Cualquiera que tuviera acceso al código tendría acceso a la citada clave, que es un valor de configuración. Es un problema de seguridad.
2. Cambiar la clave llegado el caso implicará hacer una subida de código. Va contra el principio de responsabilidad única, y contra el sentido común.

En los 12 factores de diseño de microservicios (pero si es un monolito es lo mismo) puedes leer:
*La prueba de fuego para saber si una aplicación tiene toda su configuración correctamente separada del código es comprobar que el código base puede convertirse en código abierto en cualquier momento, sin comprometer las credenciales.*

Lo correcto es:

En algún fichero de configuraciones que esté separado, o en una tabla de la base de datos a la que puedas restringir los permisos si lo necesitas.

Answer (score 2):

En un fichero de configuraciones suele ser lo habitual.

**twelve factor** si bien es orientado a SaaS (Software como servicio) tiene unas pautas bastante útiles para todo tipo de desarrollo:

https://12factor.net/es/config

> La configuración de una aplicación es todo lo que puede variar entre
>   despliegues (entornos de preproducción, producción, desarrollo, etc),
>   lo cual incluye:
>
> - Recursos que manejan la base de datos, Memcached, y otros “backing
>     services”
> - Credenciales para servicios externos tales como Amazon S3 o
>     Twitter
> - Valores de despliegue como por ejemplo el nombre canónico del
>     equipo para el despliegue
>
> A veces las aplicaciones guardan
>   configuraciones como constantes en el código, lo que conduce a una
>   violación de la metodología “twelve-factor”, que requiere una estricta
>   separación de la configuración y el código. La configuración varía
>   sustancialmente en cada despliegue, el código no.
>
> La prueba de fuego para saber si una aplicación tiene toda su
>   configuración correctamente separada del código es comprobar que el
>   código base puede convertirse en código abierto en cualquier momento,
>   sin comprometer las credenciales.

En plataformas específicas hay mecanismos que pueden ayudar, en este hilo hay algunas opciones generales https://security.stackexchange.com/a/12334/174451

Y en este algo mas orientado a windows https://security.stackexchange.com/q/32625/174451